# TFS download code checked in against a Work item

Tags: .net, tfs, changeset, workitem

On TFS, I have checked in few files of code against a Work Item today with ID: xxxx. So probably TFS might have created a changeset with a changesetID associating with that check in. Is there a way to get the code(those changed files) checked in against a workitem  by just knowing the work item ID.
i would like to do it either programatically(c# .net) or using command line.
I am a newbie to TFS, so pardon me if i am missing something very simple here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w51xa47k.aspx) documentation on msdn for more information about the `changeset` command and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx) for the `history` command.

For example to view change set details you can type:

```
tf changeset 8675309 /noprompt
```

**EDIT:**

Try this [link](http://rstonkus.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-get-files-associated-to-specified-work-item-from-tfs/) which contains a c# code that gets the files associated with a work item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me briefly reframe my question. I have a WorkItem ID, I want to download the code that is checked in against that workItem. I dont have the changeset ID. I am confused.

Comment: Check the new link above. Is that what are you looking for?